# Is there any pythonic way to combine two dicts (adding values for keys that appear in both)?

Tags: python, dictionary

For example I have two dicts:

```
Dict A: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
Dict B: {'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 5}
```

I need a pythonic way of 'combining' two dicts such that the result is:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 5, 'c': 7, 'd': 5}
```

That is to say: if a key appears in both dicts, add their values, if it appears in only one dict, keep its value.

Answer (score 910, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> A = Counter({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})
>>> B = Counter({'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':5})
>>> A + B
Counter({'c': 7, 'b': 5, 'd': 5, 'a': 1})
```

Counters are basically a subclass of `dict`, so you can still do everything else with them you'd normally do with that type, such as iterate over their keys and values.

Comment: What of there are multiple Counters to merge like this? `sum(counters)` does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: Give `sum()` a starting value, with `sum(counters, Counter())`.

Comment: Thanks. However, this method is affected by intermediate-object-creation as summing strings is, right?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: Your other option is to use a loop and `+=` to do in-place summing. `res = counters[0]`, then `for c in counters[1:]: res += c`.

Comment: I like that approach! If someone likes keep things close to processing dictionaries, one could also use `update()` instead of `+=`: `for c in counters[1:]: res.update(c)`.

Comment: What when i have not two but multiple (100 Dicts), which are in a list, is there an elaborate way?

Comment: @MartijnPieters see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226485/how-to-stop-collections-counter-from-omitting-a-key-if-its-value-is-0 here for where this almost works but breaks down when the sum of values for a given key is 0.

Comment: @Pyderman: Use `Counter.update()` if you don't want to drop the `0` values; e.g. `C = A.copy(); C.update(B)`. See [combining two python dictionaries into one when the net values are not positive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646303/combining-two-python-dictionaries-into-one-when-the-net-values-are-not-positive)

Comment: @EricWang: That's demonstrably not true. from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter): *Counts are allowed to be any integer value including zero or negative counts.* and *Several mathematical operations are provided for combining Counter objects to produce multisets (counters that have counts greater than zero). [...] Each operation can accept inputs with signed counts, but the output will exclude results with counts of zero or less.*

Comment: @EricWang: also read the section starting with ***Note**: Counters were primarily designed to work with positive integers to represent running counts; however, care was taken to not unnecessarily preclude use cases needing other types or negative values.* So *certain operations* only work with positive integers, but negative integers and floats are not outside the scope of `Counter` objects otherwise.

Comment: Note to self: check whether this maintains order with `OrderedDict`.  I think it didn't with plain `{}` dictionaries

Comment: @Nathan not sure what there is to check? Counter is a subclass of dict, not OrderedDict.  If you are using Python 3.6 or newer it preserves insertion order.

Answer (score 128):

A more generic solution, which works for non-numeric values as well:

```
a = {'a': 'foo', 'b':'bar', 'c': 'baz'}
b = {'a': 'spam', 'c':'ham', 'x': 'blah'}

r = dict(a.items() + b.items() +
    [(k, a[k] + b[k]) for k in set(b) & set(a)])
```

or even more generic:

```
def combine_dicts(a, b, op=operator.add):
    return dict(a.items() + b.items() +
        [(k, op(a[k], b[k])) for k in set(b) & set(a)])
```

For example:

```
>>> a = {'a': 2, 'b':3, 'c':4}
>>> b = {'a': 5, 'c':6, 'x':7}

>>> import operator
>>> print combine_dicts(a, b, operator.mul)
{'a': 10, 'x': 7, 'c': 24, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: You could also use `for k in b.viewkeys() & a.viewkeys()`, when [using python 2.7](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/), and skip the creation of sets.

Comment: Why does `set(a)` return the set of keys rather set of tuples?  What's the rationale for this?

Comment: @HaiPhan: because dicts iterate over keys, not over kv-pairs.  cf `list({..})`, `for k in {...}` etc

Comment: I know this is old but the final line of this seems to multiply the values and not add them as OP wanted...

Comment: @Craicerjack: yep, I used `operator.mul` to make clear that this code is generic and not limited to adding numbers.

Comment: Could you add a Python 3-compatible option? `{**a, **b, **{k: op(a[k], b[k]) for k in a.keys() & b}}` should work in Python 3.5+.

Comment: This (a.items() + b.items()) hasn't worked for a very long time.  See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/.   list(a.items()) + list(b.items()) does work.

Comment: @Dave: as you can see from the print statement, this is python2 code. It works just fine as of python 2.7.10

Answer (score 84):

```
>>> A = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> B = {'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':5}
>>> c = {x: A.get(x, 0) + B.get(x, 0) for x in set(A).union(B)}
>>> print(c)

{'a': 1, 'c': 7, 'b': 5, 'd': 5}
```

Comment: Wouldn't using `for x in set(itertools.chain(A, B))` be more logical? As using set on dict is a bit of a nonsense as keys are already unique? I know it's just another way to get a set of the keys but I find it more confusing than using `itertools.chain` (implying you know what `itertools.chain` does)

Comment: Good answer; it deserves upvotes. Better to convert `keys` to a `set` directly and skip `itertools.chain`. Why make things more complicated?

Answer (score 48):

**Intro:**
There are the (probably) best solutions. But you have to know it and remember it and sometimes you have to hope that your Python version isn't too old or whatever the issue could be.

Then there are the most 'hacky' solutions. They are great and short but sometimes are hard to understand, to read and to remember.

There is, though, an alternative which is to to try to reinvent the wheel.
- Why reinventing the wheel?
- Generally because it's a really good way to learn (and sometimes just because the already-existing tool doesn't do exactly what you would like and/or the way you would like it) and the easiest way if you don't know or don't remember the perfect tool for your problem.

**So**, I propose to reinvent the wheel of the `Counter` class from the `collections` module (partially at least):

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __add__(self, oth):
        r = self.copy()

        try:
            for key, val in oth.items():
                if key in r:
                    r[key] += val  # You can custom it here
                else:
                    r[key] = val
        except AttributeError:  # In case oth isn't a dict
            return NotImplemented  # The convention when a case isn't handled

        return r

a = MyDict({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})
b = MyDict({'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':5})

print(a+b)  # Output {'a':1, 'b': 5, 'c': 7, 'd': 5}
```

There would probably others way to implement that and there are already tools to do that but it's always nice to visualize how things would basically works.

Comment: Nice for those of us still on 2.6 also

Answer (score 18):

Definitely summing the `Counter()`s is the most pythonic way to go in such cases but **only if it results in a positive value**. Here is an example and as you can see there is no `c` in result after negating the `c`'s value in `B` dictionary.

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: A = Counter({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})

In [3]: B = Counter({'b':3, 'c':-4, 'd':5})

In [4]: A + B
Out[4]: Counter({'d': 5, 'b': 5, 'a': 1})
```

That's because `Counter`s were primarily designed to work with positive integers to represent running counts (negative count is meaningless). But to help with those use cases,python documents the minimum range and type restrictions as follows:

> - The Counter class itself is a dictionary
>     subclass with no restrictions on its keys and values. The values are
>     intended to be numbers representing counts, but you could store
>     anything in the value field.
> - The `most_common()` method requires only
>     that the values be orderable.
> - For in-place operations such as `c[key]`
>     `+= 1`, the value type need only support addition and subtraction. So fractions, floats, and decimals would work and negative values are
>     supported. The same is also true for `update()` and `subtract()` which
>     allow negative and zero values for both inputs and outputs.
> - The multiset methods are designed only for use cases with positive values.
>     The inputs may be negative or zero, but only outputs with positive
>     values are created. There are no type restrictions, but the value type
>     needs to support addition, subtraction, and comparison.
> - The `elements()` method requires integer counts. It ignores zero and negative counts.

So for getting around that problem after summing your Counter you can use `Counter.update` in order to get the desire output. It works like `dict.update()` but adds counts instead of replacing them.

```
In [24]: A.update(B)

In [25]: A
Out[25]: Counter({'d': 5, 'b': 5, 'a': 1, 'c': -1})
```

Answer (score 16):

```
myDict = {}
for k in itertools.chain(A.keys(), B.keys()):
    myDict[k] = A.get(k, 0)+B.get(k, 0)
```

Comment: You might want to wrap `itertools.chain(A.keys(), B.keys())` into a `set()` to avoid re-calculating the same key twice.

Answer (score 13):

The one with **no extra imports!**

Their is a *pythonic standard* called [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)(Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission). Below code is based on that *python standard*.

```
# The A and B dictionaries
A = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
B = {'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 5}

# The final dictionary. Will contain the final outputs.
newdict = {}

# Make sure every key of A and B get into the final dictionary 'newdict'.
newdict.update(A)
newdict.update(B)

# Iterate through each key of A.
for i in A.keys():

    # If same key exist on B, its values from A and B will add together and
    # get included in the final dictionary 'newdict'.
    try:
        addition = A[i] + B[i]
        newdict[i] = addition

    # If current key does not exist in dictionary B, it will give a KeyError,
    # catch it and continue looping.
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

EDIT: thanks to [jerzyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646765/jerzyk) for his improvement suggestions.

Comment: n^2 algorith will be significantly slower than Counter method

Comment: @DeveshSaini better, but still sub-optimal :) e.g: do you really need sorting? and then, why two loops? you already have all keys in the newdict, just small hints to optimize

Comment: n^1 algorithm has been placed instead of previous n^2 algorithm @Joop

Answer (score 12):

```
import itertools
import collections

dictA = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dictB = {'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':5}

new_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
# use dict.items() instead of dict.iteritems() for Python3
for k, v in itertools.chain(dictA.iteritems(), dictB.iteritems()):
    new_dict[k] += v

print dict(new_dict)

# OUTPUT
{'a': 1, 'c': 7, 'b': 5, 'd': 5}
```

OR

Alternative you can use Counter as @Martijn has mentioned above.

Answer (score 8):

For a more generic and extensible way check [mergedict](https://github.com/schettino72/mergedict/). It uses `singledispatch` and can merge values based on its types.

Example:

```
from mergedict import MergeDict

class SumDict(MergeDict):
    @MergeDict.dispatch(int)
    def merge_int(this, other):
        return this + other

d2 = SumDict({'a': 1, 'b': 'one'})
d2.merge({'a':2, 'b': 'two'})

assert d2 == {'a': 3, 'b': 'two'}
```

Answer (score 7):

## From python 3.5: merging and summing

Thanks to @tokeinizer_fsj that told me in a comment that I didn't get completely the meaning of the question (I thought that add meant just adding keys that eventually where different in the two dictinaries and, instead, i meant that the common key values should be summed). So I added that loop before the merging, so that the second dictionary contains the sum of the common keys. The last dictionary will be the one whose values will last in the new dictionary that is the result of the merging of the two, so I thing the problem is solved. The solution is valid from python 3.5 and following versions.

```
a = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
}

b = {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 3,
    "d": 5
}

# Python 3.5

for key in b:
    if key in a:
        b[key] = b[key] + a[key]

c = {**a, **b}
print(c)

>>> c
{'a': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 3, 'd': 5}
```

### Reusable code

```
a = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
b = {'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 5}


def mergsum(a, b):
    for k in b:
        if k in a:
            b[k] = b[k] + a[k]
    c = {**a, **b}
    return c


print(mergsum(a, b))
```

Comment: This way of merging dictionaries it's not adding the values for common keys. In the question, the desired value for key `b` is `5` (2+3), but your method is returning `3`.

Answer (score 6):

Additionally, please note `a.update( b )` is 2x faster than `a + b`

```
from collections import Counter
a = Counter({'menu': 20, 'good': 15, 'happy': 10, 'bar': 5})
b = Counter({'menu': 1, 'good': 1, 'bar': 3})

%timeit a + b;
## 100000 loops, best of 3: 8.62 µs per loop
## The slowest run took 4.04 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.

%timeit a.update(b)
## 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.51 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 6):

One line solution is to use dictionary comprehension.

```
C = { k: A.get(k,0) + B.get(k,0) for k in list(B.keys()) + list(A.keys()) }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def merge_with(f, xs, ys):
    xs = a_copy_of(xs) # dict(xs), maybe generalizable?
    for (y, v) in ys.iteritems():
        xs[y] = v if y not in xs else f(xs[x], v)

merge_with((lambda x, y: x + y), A, B)
```

You could easily generalize this:

```
def merge_dicts(f, *dicts):
    result = {}
    for d in dicts:
        for (k, v) in d.iteritems():
            result[k] = v if k not in result else f(result[k], v)
```

Then it can take any number of dicts.

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple solution for merging two dictionaries where `+=` can be applied to the values, it has to iterate over a dictionary only once

```
a = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

dicts = [{'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':5},
         {'c':9, 'a':9, 'd':9}]

def merge_dicts(merged,mergedfrom):
    for k,v in mergedfrom.items():
        if k in merged:
            merged[k] += v
        else:
            merged[k] = v
    return merged

for dct in dicts:
    a = merge_dicts(a,dct)
print (a)
#{'c': 16, 'b': 5, 'd': 14, 'a': 10}
```

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions are great for the scenario where you have a small number of `Counter`s. If you have a big list of them though, something like this is much nicer:

```
from collections import Counter

A = Counter({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3})
B = Counter({'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':5}) 
C = Counter({'a': 5, 'e':3})
list_of_counts = [A, B, C]

total = sum(list_of_counts, Counter())

print(total)
# Counter({'c': 7, 'a': 6, 'b': 5, 'd': 5, 'e': 3})
```

The above solution is essentially summing the `Counter`s by:

```
total = Counter()
for count in list_of_counts:
    total += count
print(total)
# Counter({'c': 7, 'a': 6, 'b': 5, 'd': 5, 'e': 3})
```

This does the same thing but I think it always helps to see what it is effectively doing underneath.

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another option using dictionary comprehensions combined with the behavior of `dict()`:

```
dict3 = dict(dict1, **{ k: v + dict1.get(k, 0) for k, v in dict2.items() })
# {'a': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 7, 'g': 1}
```

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict:

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict

and also

> If keyword arguments are given, the keyword arguments and their values are added to the dictionary created from the positional argument.

The dict comprehension

```
**{ k: v + dict1.get(v, 0), v in dict2.items() }
```

handles adding dict1[1] to `v`.  We don't need an explicit `if` here because the default value for our `dict1.get` can be set to 0 instead.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is easy to use, it is used as a normal dictionary, but you can use the sum function.

```
class SumDict(dict):
    def __add__(self, y):
        return {x: self.get(x, 0) + y.get(x, 0) for x in set(self).union(y)}

A = SumDict({'a': 1, 'c': 2})
B = SumDict({'b': 3, 'c': 4})  # Also works: B = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}
print(A + B)  # OUTPUT {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
def dict_merge_and_sum( d1, d2 ):
    ret = d1
    ret.update({ k:v + d2[k] for k,v in d1.items() if k in d2 })
    ret.update({ k:v for k,v in d2.items() if k not in d1 })
    return ret

A = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
B = {'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 5}

print( dict_merge_and_sum( A, B ) )
```

Output:

```
{'d': 5, 'a': 1, 'c': 7, 'b': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

More conventional way to combine two dict. Using modules and tools are good but understanding the logic behind it will help in case you don't remember the tools.

Program to combine two dictionary adding values for common keys.

```
def combine_dict(d1,d2):

for key,value in d1.items():
  if key in d2:
    d2[key] += value
  else:
      d2[key] = value
return d2

combine_dict({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3},{'b':3, 'c':4, 'd':5})

output == {'b': 5, 'c': 7, 'd': 5, 'a': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very general solution. You can deal with any number of dict + keys that are only in some dict + easily use any aggregation function you want:

```py
def aggregate_dicts(dicts, operation=sum):
    """Aggregate a sequence of dictionaries using `operation`."""
    all_keys = set().union(*[el.keys() for el in dicts])
    return {k: operation([dic.get(k, None) for dic in dicts]) for k in all_keys}
```

example:

```py
dicts_same_keys = [{'x': 0, 'y': 1}, {'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 2, 'y': 3}]
aggregate_dicts(dicts_same_keys, operation=sum)
#{'x': 3, 'y': 6}
```

example non-identical keys and generic aggregation:

```py
dicts_diff_keys = [{'x': 0, 'y': 1}, {'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'c': 4}]

def mean_no_none(l):
    l_no_none = [el for el in l if el is not None]
    return sum(l_no_none) / len(l_no_none)

aggregate_dicts(dicts_diff_keys, operation=mean_no_none)
# {'x': 1.0, 'c': 4.0, 'y': 2.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dict2 = {'a':3, 'g':1, 'c':4}
dict3 = {} # will store new values

for x in dict1:
    
    if x in dict2: #sum values with same key
        dict3[x] = dict1[x] +dict2[x]
    else: #add the values from x to dict1
        dict3[x] = dict1[x]
        
#search for new values not in a
for x in dict2:
    if x not in dict1:
        dict3[x] = dict2[x]
print(dict3) # {'a': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 7, 'g': 1}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Merging three dicts a,b,c in a single line without any other modules or libs

If we have the three dicts

```
a = {"a":9}
b = {"b":7}
c = {'b': 2, 'd': 90}
```

Merge all with a single line and return a dict object using

```
c = dict(a.items() + b.items() + c.items())
```

Returning

```
{'a': 9, 'b': 2, 'd': 90}
```

Comment: Reread the question, this is not the expected output. It should have been with your inputs: `{'a': 9, 'b': 9, 'd': 90}`. You are missing the "sum" requirement.