# Combine two dictionaries, concatenate string values?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Related: [Is there any pythonic way to combine two dicts (adding values for keys that appear in both)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe?lq=1)

I'd like to merge two string:string dictionaries, and concatenate the values. The above post recommends using `collections.Counter`, but it doesn't handle string concatenation.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = Counter({'foo':'bar', 'baz':'bazbaz'})
>>> b = Counter({'foo':'baz'})
>>> a + b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 569, in __add__
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

(My guess is Counter tries to set `b['baz']` to 0.)

I'd like to get a result of `{'foo':'barbaz', 'baz':'bazbaz'}`. Concatenation order doesn't matter to me. What is a clean, Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: What will be the expected output if the second dict looks like : `{'foo':'baz','spam':'eggs'}`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary {'foo':'barbaz', 'baz':'bazbaz', 'spam':'eggs'}

Comment: `collections.Counter` is **specifically** for dictionaries where the value is an *integer that conceptually represents a count*. It cannot help with anything else.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dict-comprehension:

```
>>> d = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'bazbaz'}
>>> d1 = {'foo': 'baz'}
>>> keys = d.viewkeys() | d1.viewkeys()
>>> {k : d.get(k, '') + d1.get(k, '') for k in keys}
{'foo': 'barbaz', 'baz': 'bazbaz'}
```

For Python 2.6 and earlier:

```
>>> dict((k, d.get(k, '') + d1.get(k, '')) for k in keys)
{'foo': 'barbaz', 'baz': 'bazbaz'}
```

This will work for any number of dicts:

```
def func(*dicts):
    keys = set().union(*dicts)
    return {k: "".join(dic.get(k, '') for dic in dicts)  for k in keys}
... 
>>> d = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'bazbaz'}
>>> d1 = {'foo': 'baz','spam': 'eggs'}
>>> d2 = {'foo': 'foofoo', 'spam': 'bar'}
>>> func(d, d1, d2)
{'foo': 'barbazfoofoo', 'baz': 'bazbaz', 'spam': 'eggsbar'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can write a generic helper, such as:

```
a = {'foo':'bar', 'baz':'bazbaz'}
b = {'foo':'baz'}

def concatd(*dicts):
    if not dicts:
        return {} # or should this be None or an exception?
    fst = dicts[0]
    return {k: ''.join(d.get(k, '') for d in dicts) for k in fst}

print concatd(a, b)
# {'foo': 'barbaz', 'baz': 'bazbaz'}

c = {'foo': '**not more foo!**'}
print concatd(a, b, c)
# {'foo': 'barbaz**not more foo!**', 'baz': 'bazbaz'}
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to achieve this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'bazbaz'}
b = {'foo': 'baz'}

new_dict = defaultdict(str)
for key, value in a.items():
    new_dict[key] += value
for key, value in b.items():
    new_dict[key] += value

print(new_dict)
# defaultdict(<class 'str'>, {'foo': 'barbaz', 'baz': 'bazbaz'})
print(dict(new_dict))
# {'foo': 'barbaz', 'baz': 'bazbaz'}
```

If there are many dicts to join, we could use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

a = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'bazbaz'}
b = {'foo': 'baz'}
c = {'baz': '123'}
dicts = [a, b, c]

new_dict = defaultdict(str)
for key, value in chain.from_iterable(map(dict.items, dicts)):
    new_dict[key] += value

print(dict(new_dict))
# {'foo': 'barbaz', 'baz': 'bazbaz123'}
```