# Counting the number of lists that contain an element in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

How to create a list which contains the number of times an element appears in a number of lists. for example I have these lists:

```
list1 = ['apples','oranges','grape']
list2 = ['oranges, 'oranges', 'pear']
list3 = ['strawberries','bananas','apples']
list4 = [list1,list2,list3]
```

I want to count the number of documents that contain each element and put it in a dictionary, so for apples^and oranges I get this:

```
term['apples'] = 2
term['oranges'] = 2   #not 3
```

Comment: `term['apples']` implies the use of a dict.

Comment: what do you need the count to be for 'oranges'? 2 or 3?

Comment: 2...the number of documents :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> [el for lst in [set(L) for L in list4] for el in lst].count('apples')
2
>>> [el for lst in [set(L) for L in list4] for el in lst].count('oranges')
2
```

If you want the final structure as a dictionary, a dict comprehension can be used to create a histogram from the flattened list of sets:

```
>>> list4sets = [set(L) for L in list4]
>>> list4flat = [el for lst in list4sets for el in lst]
>>> term = {el: list4flat.count(el) for el in list4flat}
>>> term['apples']
2
>>> term['oranges']
2
```

Comment: isn't `el` a list? how can you use it as a key in the dict?

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
terms = Counter( x for lst in list4 for x in lst )
terms
=> Counter({'oranges': 3, 'apples': 2, 'grape': 1, 'bananas': 1, 'pear': 1, 'strawberries': 1})
terms['apples']
=> 2
```

As @Stuart pointed out, you can also use `chain.from_iterable`, to avoid the awkward-looking double-loop in the generator expression (i.e. the `for lst in list4 for x in lst`).

EDIT: another cool trick is to take the sum of the `Counter`s (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe/11011846#11011846) famous answer), like:

`sum(( Counter(lst) for lst in list4 ), Counter())`

Comment: I don't think list4 is ment to be included.

Comment: thank you, but problem is, I want to get the number of lists that this term appears in, for example if a list has it 5 times it should still count as one count...terms['apple'] gives the number of occurrence of this term in all documents, and not the number of documents that have apple

Comment: ah, in that case, use `set`s instead of lists, to remove duplicates. e.g. `list4 = [ set(list1), set(list2), set(list3) ]`. With that, the answer is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
print (list1 + list2 + list3).count('apples')
```

or if you have all the lists already compiled in `list4`, you could use `itertools.chain` as a quick way to link them:

```
from itertools import chain
print list(chain.from_iterable(list4)).count('apples')
```

EDIT: or you can do this without `itertools`:

```
print sum(list4, []).count('apples')
```

and could easily replicate `collections.Counter` if for some reason you wanted to...

```
all_lists = sum(list4, [])
print dict((k, all_lists.count(k)) for k in set(all_lists))
```