# How to subtract values from dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries in Python:

```
d1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 9, 'c': 8, 'd': 7}
d2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 2}
```

I want to substract values between dictionaries d1-d2 and get the result:

```
d3 = {'a': 9, 'b': 7, 'c': 5, 'd': 7 }
```

Now I'm using two loops but this solution is not too fast

```
for x,i in enumerate(d2.keys()):
        for y,j in enumerate(d1.keys()):
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any pythonic way to combine two dicts (adding values for keys that appear in both)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think a very Pythonic way would be using [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
d3 = {key: d1[key] - d2.get(key, 0) for key in d1}
```

Note that this only works in Python 2.7+ or 3.

Comment: This is the fastest solution. Performance tested using two dictionaries with 1M elements each.

Comment: You don't actually need the `.keys()` on the end there.

Comment: Also, for anyone that wants to remove keys that are 0 or less, you can modify this to: `{key: d1[key]-d2.get(key, 0) for key in d1 if d1[key]-d2.get(key, 0)>0}`

Answer (score 25):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), iif all resulting values are known to be strictly positive. The syntax is very easy:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d1 = Counter({'a': 10, 'b': 9, 'c': 8, 'd': 7})
>>> d2 = Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 2})
>>> d3 = d1 - d2
>>> print d3
Counter({'a': 9, 'b': 7, 'd': 7, 'c': 5})
```

Mind, if not all values are known to remain *strictly* positive:

- elements with values that become zero will be omitted in the result
- elements with values that become negative will be missing, or replaced with wrong values. E.g., `print(d2-d1)` can yield `Counter({'e': 2})`.

Comment: ... I didn't know you could do that with Counter O.O

Comment: @alvas collections.Counter doesn't support division/multiplication

Comment: I think this is more pythonic than the accepted answer

Comment: Only negative here is that it won't work if the result is negative

Comment: I can't remember. Does `collections.Counter()` also work with floats?

Answer (score 14):

Just an update to Haidro answer.

Recommended to use subtract method instead of  "-".

d1.subtract(d2)

When - is used, only positive counters are updated into dictionary.
See examples below

```
c = Counter(a=4, b=2, c=0, d=-2)
d = Counter(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
a = c-d
print(a)        # --> Counter({'a': 3})
c.subtract(d)
print(c)        # --> Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 0, 'c': -3, 'd': -6})
```

Please note the dictionary is updated when subtract method is used.

And finally use dict(c) to get Dictionary from Counter object

Comment: Do you mind if I add this into my answer? I'll reference yours :)

Comment: Actually, while testing this, it doesn't returned the OP's wanted dictionary. This returns `e = -2`, where the OP just wants to remove the `e`.

Comment: And, although not a major problem, it doesn't return the subtracted dictionary (but really, I don't think this will matter)

Comment: Also note that `subtract` can handle `dict` types, so there is no need to convert `d`.

Comment: Yessss finally needed this bit of code for negatives!

Comment: what if I dont want to change Counter c. i want to assign the result to a variable. i try it give me a None type.  anyway to use e = c.subtract(d) ?

Comment: copy the original counter and then subtract

Answer (score 4):

Haidro posted an easy solution, but even without `collections` you only need one loop:

```
d1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 9, 'c': 8, 'd': 7}
d2 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'e': 2}
d3 = {}

for k, v in d1.items():
    d3[k] = v - d2.get(k, 0) # returns value if k exists in d2, otherwise 0

print(d3) # {'c': 5, 'b': 7, 'a': 9, 'd': 7}
```