# More pythonic way to remove duplcate key/values from dict inside two diferent lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using python 2.7 what would be the proper approach to return only what is different from a set of dictionaries on two different lists? The code bellow is works, but I'm sure there's a better way to do it but I'm not sure how it could be achieved.

```
l_current = [{'type': 'food', 'drink': 'water'},{'type': 'food', 'drink': 'other'}]
l_new = [{'type': 'food', 'drink': 'other'},
         {'type': 'food', 'drink': 'dirt'},
         {'type': 'food', 'drink': 'gasoline'}]
l_final = []
for curr in l_current:
    for new in l_new:
        nkey = new['propertie_key']
        ckey = curr['propertie_key']
        nval = new['propertie_value']
        cval = curr['propertie_value']
        if nkey == ckey:
            if nval != cval:
                d_final = {nkey: nval}
                l_final.append(d_final)
```

**Desired Output**
It would be **only** what is different from the l_new regarding l_current:

```
[{'type': 'food', 'drink': 'dirt'},{'type': 'food', 'drink': 'gasoline'}]
```

Edit: It's not a homework, I'm just trying to optimize a current working code.

Edit 2: The desired output is already there, After some searching on google I was able to find some solutions like the following ones, but I'm not sure how could i implement it.

[remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python)

[how-to-subtract-values-from-dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671875/how-to-subtract-values-from-dictionaries)

Comment: Can you please post the desired output?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, sure, let me edit the question.

Comment: The first link is *broken* and I still do not see the desired output..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis just finished. I was interrupted by a coworker :)

Comment: What is considered "different"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand this correctly it is as simple as that:

```
l_current = [{'type': 'food', 'drink': 'water'},{'type': 'food', 'drink': 'other'}]
l_new = [{'type': 'food', 'drink': 'other'},
         {'type': 'food', 'drink': 'dirt'},
         {'type': 'food', 'drink': 'gasoline'}]

l_final = [x for x in l_new if x not in l_current]
print(l_final)  # [{'drink': 'dirt', 'type': 'food'}, {'drink': 'gasoline', 'type': 'food'}]
```

You can compare dictionaries the same way you compare any other object in Python and that is the reason the above list comprehension works; *testing for membership boils down to an equality check*.

Comment: Just perfect. THank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

From your given example you can achieve the desired result in a list comprehension:

```
l_final = [item for item in l_new if item not in l_current]
```

This should check each item in the new list and store it in the final list if the current list element is not present.