# How to get the position of an element relative to canvas element using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

i want to know the position of an element relative to the canvas element.

i initially create a point at x and y values being -50 and -50
like below using selenium webdriver

```
canvas = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='canvas_holder']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(canvas).move_by_offset(-50, -50).click().perform()
```

The above creates a point. now i have to check if the point is created at -50 and -50 how can i do it.

could anyone provide me some ideas. thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it on [Selenium: get coordinates or dimensions of element with Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15511365/12036063)

> Got it! The clue was on [selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement — Selenium 3.14 documentation.](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html)
>
> WebElements have the properties `.size` and `.location`. Both are of type `dict`.
>
> ```
> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>
> e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//someXpath")
>
> location = e.location
> size = e.size
>
> print(location)
> print(size)
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> {'y': 202, 'x': 165}
> {'width': 77, 'height': 22}
> ```
>
> They also have a property called [`rect`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.rect) which is itself a `dict`, and contains the element's `size` and `location`.

Then subtract the position of the element you want from its parent position.
For example, if `d1` is the `parentElement.location`, and `d2` is the `childElement.location`,

then, [python - How to subtract values from dictionaries - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671875/how-to-subtract-values-from-dictionaries/17672180#17672180)

> I think a very Pythonic way would be using [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):
>
> ```
> d3 = {key: d1[key] - d2.get(key, 0) for key in d1.keys()}
> ```
>
> Note that this only works in Python 2.7+ or 3.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199901/discussion-on-answer-by-angular-orbit-how-to-get-the-position-of-an-element-rela).