# merge two dictionaries by key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I know this question has been asked but I could not find anything that appends the values to the list instead of creating a list of list. I have two dictionaries which have identical values:

```
dictionary1 = {'1':'one', '2':'two', '3':'three'}
dictionary2 = {'1':['uno'], '2':['dos'], '3':['tres']}
```

and I need it to return this:

```
combined = {'1':['one','uno'] '2':['two','dos'] '3':['three',tres']}
```

so far everything I tried returns this:

```
combined = {'1':['one'['uno']] '2':['two'['dos']] '3':['three'[tres']]}
```

which has nested lists. How do I append the values of dictionary 1 into the dictionary2 list? Please help me, I know is really simple but I don't know how to do it. thank you

Here is my code:

```
    combined = {key:[dictionary1[key], dictionary2[key]] for key in dictionary1}
```

Comment: Erm.. that code should work, and give you what you want.

Comment: Your code returns what you want.

Comment: @DSM that is giving me combined = {'1':['one',['uno']] '2':['two',['dos']] '3':['three',[tres']]}  
I don't understand why. is there another way to do it?

Comment: @April: respectfully, I don't believe you.  :-)  If you copy and paste your first two lines into a console, and then your `combined = {key: et cetera` line, you'll get your target.  Maybe your `dictionary2` is wrong, and has lists instead of strings as values.

Comment: Post your full code, there is something you are not showing us.

Comment: YES! that's what it is. one of my dictionaries has a list for the values. I just realized. So how do I append the other value to the list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any pythonic way to combine two dicts (adding values for keys that appear in both)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your code is already correct?

```
>>> dictionary1 = {'1':'one', '2':'two', '3':'three'}
>>> dictionary2 = {'1':'uno', '2':'dos', '3':'tres'}
>>> combined = {key:[dictionary1[key], dictionary2[key]] for key in dictionary1}
>>> combined
{'3': ['three', 'tres'], '2': ['two', 'dos'], '1': ['one', 'uno']}
```

Are you sure you are not doing anything else besides this?

Comment: I just realized one of my dictionaries has values as list, so what I need is to append the new values to that list. how do I do that?

Comment: If dictionary2 for instance has lists as values, then you can just do this:   ``combined = {key:[dictionary1[key]] +  dictionary2[key] for key in dictionary1}`` .. if dictionary1 holds lists as values as well then remove the surrounding ``[]`` for  ``dictionary1[key]``. We're just concatenating lists here.

Comment: how could you do this in separate lines with a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary1 = {'1':'one', '2':'two', '3':'three'}
dictionary2 = {'1':['uno'], '2':['dos'], '3':['tres']}

combined = {key:[dictionary1[key], dictionary2[key][0]] for key in dictionary1}
```

Simply retrieve the 0th index from the values of `dictionary2`, considering they're all lists of length 1.

Otherwise, this will work:

```
combined = {key:[dictionary1[key]] + dictionary2[key] for key in dictionary1}
```

This basically creates a one element list out of the values of `dictionary1` and combines it with the values of `dictionary2` which are already lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary1 = {'1':'one', '2':'two', '3':'three'}
dictionary2 = {'1':'uno', '2':'dos', '3':'tres'}


z = zip(zip(dictionary1.keys(), dictionary2.keys()),
        zip(dictionary1.values(), dictionary2.values()))

dual = {}

for el in z:
    dual[el[0][0]] = el[1]


print(list(dual.items()))
```

**OUPUT**

[('2', ('two', 'dos')), ('1', ('one', 'uno')), ('3', ('three', 'tres'))]