# What is the fastest way to combine and sort lists of tuples?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of lists of tuples. Each tuple has the form `(string,int)`, e.g.

```
lst = list()
lst.append([('a',5),('c',10),('d',3),('b',1)])
lst.append([('c',14),('f',4),('b',1)])
lst.append([('d',22),('f',2)])
```

Think of the `int`'s as counts of each string in different blocks of text.

What I need to do is produce a list of top-`N` occurring strings together with their cumulative counts. So in the example above, `a` appears 5 times, `b` appears twice, `c` appears 24 times etc. If `N=2`, then I would have to produce either a pair of parallel lists `['d','c']` and `[25,24]` or a list of tuples `[('d',25),('c',24)]`. I need to do it as quickly as possible. My machine has lots of RAM so memory is not an issue.

I have this implementation:

```
import numpy as np
def getTopN(lst,N):

    sOut = []
    cOut = []

    for l in lst:
        for tpl in l:
            s = tpl[0]
            c = tpl[1]

            try:
                i = sOut.index(s)
                cOut[i] += c
            except:
                sOut.append(s)
                cOut.append(c)

    sIndAsc = np.argsort(cOut).tolist()
    sIndDes = sIndAsc[::-1]
    cOutDes = [cOut[sir] for sir in sIndDes]
    sOutDes = [sOut[sir] for sir in sIndDes]

    return sOutDes[0:N],cOutDes[0:N]
```

There's gotta be a better way, but what would it be?

Comment: Is there any reason why the list is of lists of tuples? Does the problem become different if we just change it into a list of 2-tuples?

Comment: *Think of the int's as counts of each string in different blocks of text.* -- why not `collections.Counter`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any pythonic way to combine two dicts (adding values for keys that appear in both)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe)

Comment: Are the strings always single characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter()
for x in lst:
    c.update(dict(x))
print(c.most_common(2))
```

Output:

```
[('d', 25), ('c', 24)]
```

The `Counter` is basically a dictionary with some added functionality, so looking up a value and adding to it's current count is really fast. `dict(x)` will just turn the list of tuples into a regular dict, mapping strings to numbers, then the `update` method of `Counter` will add those counts (instead of just overwriting the values, as a regular dict would do).

Alternatively, a more manual approach using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
c = collections.defaultdict(int)
for x, y in (t for x in lst for t in x):
    c[x] += y
return [(k, c[k]) for k in sorted(c, key=c.get, reverse=True)][:2]
```

As pointed out by John in comments, the `defaultdict` is indeed much faster:

```
In [2]: %timeit with_counter()
10000 loops, best of 3: 17.3 µs per loop
In [3]: %timeit with_dict()
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.97 µs per loop
```

Comment: Counter is neat (and helps avoid bugs), but you will usually find that a dict or defaultdict is faster even though you need a few extra lines of code.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Thanks for pointing out, did not think it would make such a difference. Added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using `numpy`:

```
# make a flattened numpy version of the list
lst_np = np.asarray([item for sublist in lst for item in sublist])

# split into the two columns
chars = lst_np[:,0]
counts = lst_np[:,1].astype('int')

# get unique characters, and compute total counts for each
[unique_chars, unique_inds] = np.unique(chars, return_inverse=True)
unique_counts = np.asarray([np.sum(counts[unique_inds==x])
    for x in range(len(unique_chars))])
```

This will get you counts (`unique_counts`) for each unique character (`unique_chars`) in the lists, not just the top `N`. This should be pretty fast, but might be heavy on memory.