# Python - merge two lists of tuples into one list of tuples

Tags: python, list

What's the pythonic way of achieving the following?

from:

```
a = [('apple', 10), ('of', 10)]
b = [('orange', 10), ('of', 7)]
```

to get

```
c = [('orange', 10), ('of', 17), ('apple', 10)]
```

Comment: Use `collections.Counter`

Comment: Do you have an unpythonic way of doing it to start with?

Answer (score 3):

You essentially have word-counter pairs. Using `collections.Counter()` lets you handle those in a natural, Pythonic way:

```
from collections import Counter

c = (Counter(dict(a)) + Counter(dict(b))).items()
```

Also see [Is there any pythonic way to combine two dicts (adding values for keys that appear in both)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe/11011846#11011846)

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = [('apple', 10), ('of', 10)]
>>> b = [('orange', 10), ('of', 7)]
>>> Counter(dict(a)) + Counter(dict(b))
Counter({'of': 17, 'orange': 10, 'apple': 10})
>>> (Counter(dict(a)) + Counter(dict(b))).items()
[('orange', 10), ('of', 17), ('apple', 10)]
```

You could just drop the `.items()` call and keep using a `Counter()` here.

You may want to avoid building (word, count) tuples to begin with and work with `Counter()` objects from the start.

Comment: Any nice way to avoid the intermediate dictionaries? I couldn't think of one, too ...

Comment: @dhke: no 'nice' way, it is the most concise way to convert the list of (word, count) tuples to a `Counter`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was thinking of `Counter.update()` but that actually behaves differently than `dict.update()` when passed a tuple sequence.