# Dictionary merge by adding values

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have two dictionaries

```
a = {'milk':90, 'coffee':80, 'rice':100, 'Cheese': 70}

b = {'milk':90, 'coffee':80, 'pulses': 100,'Alcohol':750}
```

I want to merge these two dictionaries by adding value of common elements of the dictionaries which should give resultant as:

```
c = {'milk':180, 'coffee':160, 'rice':100, 'Cheese':70, 'pulses':100, 'Alcohol':750}
```

I am trying this at my level , please suggest if anyone have a solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `keys` of either dicts and add their value to make the third, so it doesn't matter which items are unique to just one of them. Use the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to fetch the value for each key from both dicts, defaulting to `0` if that item is not present (since we're adding).

```
>>> c = {}
>>> for key in set(a.keys() + b.keys()):
...     c[key] = a.get(key, 0) + b.get(key, 0)
...
>>> c
{'Cheese': 70, 'coffee': 160, 'Alcohol': 750, 'pulses': 100, 'rice': 100, 'milk': 180}
```

And a one-liner version of that, if you prefer:

```
>>> d = {key: a.get(key, 0) + b.get(key, 0) for key in set(a.keys() + b.keys())}
>>> d == c
True
>>>
```

Comment: Nice one. I'm not sure whose solution I like better! :)

Comment: And my answer appears to be [a close dupe of one of the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11011911/1431750) on the dupe question :-/

Comment: Indicating that it's in canonical style. (or, in the annoying idiom, "pythonic")

Comment: Hello Aneroid, 

First, I would like to thankyou for such nice source code to solve this problem. I found the one liner code is efficient and faster solution. it is a huge help. Once again thankyou. It worked for me. 

Also I came up with my solution as well which I am posting in my answer. Please do check. :)

Huge Thanks & regards,
Ripundeep Gill

Comment: You're welcome. And welcome to SO. You won't be able to add your answer/solution since this thread has been closed - as being a [duplicate of this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11011756/1431750). But if you want to share what you have done/tried or worked for you, you can add it as an Edit to your original question above.

Comment: a = {'milk':90, 'coffee':80, 'rice':100, 'Cheese': 70}, 

b = {'milk':90, 'coffee':80, 'pulses': 100,'Alcohol':750}, 

from collections import Counter

a = Counter(a)

b = Counter(b)

c = a+b

c = dict(c)

print c

**output:
{'Cheese': 70, 'coffee': 160, 'pulses': 100, 'Alcohol': 750, 'rice': 100, 'milk': 180}**

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
>>> def merge_dicts(a,b):
...   c = {}
...   for k, v in a.items():
...     c[k] = a[k] + b.get(k, 0)
...   b.update(c)
...   return b
... 
>>> merge_dicts(a,b)
{'Cheese': 70, 'coffee': 160, 'Alcohol': 750, 'pulses': 100, 'rice': 100, 'milk': 180}
>>>
```

NOTE: Please feel free to ask if there's anything you don't understand here - it's no good just learning incantations if you're not clear on why they work!

Comment: Note that you're you're creating a new dict `c` but then updating the existing dict `b` and returning that one. ie. `b` gets modified when calling `merge_dicts`.

Comment: Hello Jon, First, I would like to thank you for such nice source code to solve this problem. Making a function is one way if we need to generalize something with parameters and reusing it within code. I appreciate the way you did it.  it is a huge help. Once again thankyou. It worked for me. Also I came up with my solution as well which I am posting in my answer. Please do check. :) Huge Thanks & regards, Ripundeep Gill

Comment: a = {'milk':90, 'coffee':80, 'rice':100, 'Cheese': 70}, b = {'milk':90, 'coffee':80, 'pulses': 100,'Alcohol':750}, from collections import Counter a = Counter(a) b = Counter(b) c = a+b c = dict(c) print c output: {'Cheese': 70, 'coffee': 160, 'pulses': 100, 'Alcohol': 750, 'rice': 100, 'milk': 180}