# calculate the total value dict

Tags: python, dictionary, tf-idf

I have a problem, how to calculate the total dict of the same keys ? I have a dict:

```
{'learning': {'DOC1': 0.14054651081081646,
              'DOC2': 0,
              'DOC3': 0.4684883693693881},
 'life':     {'DOC1': 0.14054651081081646, 
              'DOC2': 0.20078072972973776, 
              'DOC3': 0}
}
```

and I hope the results as:

```
{'learning life': {
        'DOC1': DOC1 in learning + DOC1 in life,
        'DOC2': DOC2 in learning + DOC2 in life,
        'DOC3': DOC3 in learning + DOC3 in life,}}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any pythonic way to combine two dicts (adding values for keys that appear in both)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to add all the numbers nested in a dictionary `d` just like so:

```
totals = {k: sum(v.get(k, 0) for v in d.values()) for k in d.values()[0]} # dict of totals
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

```
for k in d['learning']:
    print(d['learning'][k] + d['life'][k])
```

... with `d` being your `dict` and no error checking whatsoever (does the key exist, is it really a number, etc.).

---

As whole code snippet with a comprehension:

```
d = {'learning': {'DOC1': 0.14054651081081646,
              'DOC2': 0,
              'DOC3': 0.4684883693693881},
 'life':     {'DOC1': 0.14054651081081646, 
              'DOC2': 0.20078072972973776, 
              'DOC3': 0}
}

d['sum'] = [d['learning'][k] + d['life'][k]
            for k in d['learning']]
print(d)
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/BDmyrw).

Comment: Of course, that implies that the exact same keys that are in `learning` are also in `life`. If you have different key values, you also have to check whether the key in `learning` is in `life`. This can be done by using `for key in learning.keys()` and `if key in life.keys()`