# Add values from two dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary, merge

```
dict1 = {a: 5, b: 7}
dict2 = {a: 3, c: 1}

result {a:8, b:7, c:1}
```

How can I get the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any pythonic way to combine two dicts (adding values for keys that appear in both)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

this is a one-liner that would do just that:

```
dict1 = {'a': 5, 'b': 7}
dict2 = {'a': 3, 'c': 1}

result = {key: dict1.get(key, 0) + dict2.get(key, 0)
          for key in set(dict1) | set(dict2)}
# {'c': 1, 'b': 7, 'a': 8}
```

note that `set(dict1) | set(dict2)` is the set of the keys of both your dictionaries. and `dict1.get(key, 0)` returns `dict1[key]` if the key exists, `0` otherwise.

---

this works on a more recent python version:

```
{k: dict1.get(k, 0) + dict2.get(k, 0) for k in dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) which implements addition `+` that way:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> dict1 = Counter({'a': 5, 'b': 7})
>>> dict2 = Counter({'a': 3, 'c': 1})
>>> dict1 + dict2
Counter({'a': 8, 'b': 7, 'c': 1})
```

if you really want the result as dict you can cast it back afterwards:

```
>>> dict(dict1 + dict2)
{'a': 8, 'b': 7, 'c': 1}
```

Comment: this implementation . has a problem it's not counting values that are zeros

Comment: Actually it [only keeps positive values](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5ee21732ee609805c60c60691119f3d509d50cd5/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L736), i.e. `Counter(a=0, b=1) + Counter(b=-2) == Counter()` (`+` gives an empty counter here).

Answer (score 1):

Think it's much simpler.

```
a={'a':3, 'b':5}

b= {'a':4, 'b':7}

{i:a[i]+b[i] for i in a.keys()}
```

Output: `{'a': 7, 'b': 12}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice function for you:

```
def merge_dictionaries(dict1, dict2):
    merged_dictionary = {}

    for key in dict1:
        if key in dict2:
            new_value = dict1[key] + dict2[key]
        else:
            new_value = dict1[key]

        merged_dictionary[key] = new_value

    for key in dict2:
        if key not in merged_dictionary:
            merged_dictionary[key] = dict2[key]

    return merged_dictionary
```

by writing:

```
dict1 = {'a': 5, 'b': 7}
dict2 = {'a': 3, 'c': 1}
result = merge_dictionaries(dict1, dict2)
```

result will be:

```
{'a': 8, 'b': 7, 'c': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick dictionary comprehension that should work on any classes which accept the + operator. Performance might not be optimal.

```
{
    **dict1,
    **{ k:(dict1[k]+v if k in dict1 else v)
        for k,v in dict2.items() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is another approach but it is quite lengthy!

d1 = {'a': 5, 'b': 7}
d2 = {'a': 3, 'c': 1}

d={}
for i,j in d1.items():
    for k,l in d2.items():
        if i==k:
            c={i:j+l}
            d.update(c)
for i,j in d1.items():
    if i not in d:
        d.update({i:j})
for m,n in d2.items():
    if m not in d:
        d.update({m:n})
```