# Adding contents of multiple lists of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have 2 list of dictionaries of the form:

```
a = [{'count': 10, 'name': 'ABC', 'dates':{'2018':1,'2019':4,'2020':5}}, {'count': 5, 'name': 'XYZ', 'dates':{'2018':2,'2019':4,'2020':3}}]

b = [{'count': 5, 'name': 'ABC', 'dates':{'2018':3,'2019':1,'2020':3}}, {'count': 3, 'name': 'XYZ', 'dates':{'2018':3,'2019':5,'2020':11}}]
```

Now i want to merge dictionary b into a such that each number corresponding to same date in a dictionary are added up and I get something of the following sort:

```
a = [{'count': 15, 'name': 'ABC', 'dates':{'2018':4,'2019':5,'2020':8}}, {'count': 8, 'name': 'XYZ', 'dates':{'2018':5,'2019':9,'2020':14}}]
```

How can this be achieved? I tried doing it through for loops, but it is turning out very complex. Is there a pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: Please share your tries

Comment: Maybe this is related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe

Comment: @azro tbh it got too complex for me to understand, so I left it midway.

Comment: @NewPythonUser It shows an error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/926b026e392479d8ef2cee8fb8fea506.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(A + B)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 703, in __add__
    if newcount > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.

Comment: Edit your post to add code or error, not in comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `Counter` to sum the dates' occurences

- iterate over both dict of `a` and `b`
- use the name as a key, to know whether to add the mapping or compute the sum
- when just adding, set the `dates` in a `Counter` (ready to be used later)
- when summing, add the previous counter to the new one, they'll sum together their occurences

```
result = {}
for value in a + b:
    print(value)
    if value['name'] not in result:
        result[value['name']] = value
        result[value['name']]['dates'] = Counter(value['dates'])
    else:
        result[value['name']]['dates'] += Counter(value['dates'])
        result[value['name']]['count'] += value['count']

final_result = list(result.values())
# [{'count': 15, 'name': 'ABC', 'dates': Counter({'2020': 8, '2019': 5, '2018': 4})}, {'count': 3, 'name': 'XYZ', 'dates': Counter({'2020': 14, '2019': 9, '2018': 5})}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Plain loop solution:

```
a = [{'count': 10, 'name': 'ABC', 'dates':{'2018':1,'2019':4,'2020':5}}, {'count': 5, 'name': 'XYZ', 'dates':{'2018':2,'2019':4,'2020':3}}]
b = [{'count': 5, 'name': 'ABC', 'dates':{'2018':3,'2019':1,'2020':3}}, {'count': 3, 'name': 'XYZ', 'dates':{'2018':3,'2019':5,'2020':11}}]

# loop over all items in a
for i, aItem in enumerate(a):
    # find corresponding item in b by 'name' use an empty one if not found!
    bItem = [item for item in b if item['name'] == aItem['name']] or [{}]
    bItem = bItem[0]

    # sum up the date values
    _dates = aItem['dates']
    for k,v in _dates.items():
        _dates[k] += bItem.get('dates', {}).get(k, 0)

    aItem['dates'] = _dates
    aItem['count'] += bItem.get('count', 0)

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[
{'count': 15, 'dates': {'2020': 8, '2019': 5, '2018': 4}, 'name': 'ABC'},  
{'count': 8, 'dates': {'2020': 14, '2019': 9, '2018': 5}, 'name': 'XYZ'}
]
```

Comment: Cool solution! Thanks!