# Python functions for nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Given a dictionary :

```
dic = {
    2: {'p': 0.225, 'i': 0.159, 'e': 0.116, 'c': 0.098, 'a': 0.09311},
    7: {'r': 0.186, 's': 0.148, 'd': 0.145, 'a': 0.005},
    8: {'r': 0.1, 's': 0.2}
```

I want the output as a dictionary with key as `'a'`, `'p'`, ...  and their values as the addition of their values in a nested dictionary

Expected output:

```
{'p': 0.025 , 'a' 0.09811 ....}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour]. What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. See [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace on `dic`

Comment: `{k: sum(d.get(k, 0) for d in dic.values()) for d in dic.values() for k in d.keys()}`

Comment: Why is `'p': 0.025` in the output? Shouldn't it be `0.225`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
dic = {2: {'p': 0.225, 'i': 0.159, 'e': 0.116, 'c': 0.098, 'a': 0.09311}, 7: {'r': 0.186, 's': 0.148, 'd': 0.145, 'a': 0.005},8:{'r':0.1, 's':0.2}}

res = {}

for d in dic.values():
    for k, v in d.items():
        res[k] = res.get(k, 0.0) + v

print(res) # {'p': 0.225, 'i': 0.159, 'e': 0.116, 'c': 0.098, 'a': 0.09811, 'r': 0.28600000000000003, 's': 0.348, 'd': 0.145}
```

In particular, `dict.get(key, value)` returns `dict[key]` if the latter is present, and `value` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

See [Is there any pythonic way to combine two dicts (adding values for keys that appear in both)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11011756/15497888)

Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```py
from collections import Counter

dic = {2: {'p': 0.225, 'i': 0.159, 'e': 0.116, 'c': 0.098, 'a': 0.09311},
       7: {'r': 0.186, 's': 0.148, 'd': 0.145, 'a': 0.005},
       8: {'r': 0.1, 's': 0.2}}

res = dict(sum([Counter(d) for d in dic.values()], Counter()))
print(res)
```

output:

```
{'p': 0.225, 'i': 0.159, 'e': 0.116, 'c': 0.098, 'a': 0.09811, 'r': 0.28600000000000003, 's': 0.348, 'd': 0.145}
```