# merge two dicts with custom update

Tags: python

I have two Python dictionaries, and I want to merge (union) them together but with a custom update function in case the same key exists in both dicts. For instance:

```
>>> x = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> y = {'b': 10, 'c': 11}
>>> z = {'a': 3, 'd': 5}
>>> merge(x,y,z)  # add values together if key exists in both
{'a': 4, 'b': 12, 'c': 11, 'd': 5}
```

What's the simplest way to do so?

Edit: I'm looking for a solution that works for arbitrary number of dicts to merge, and perform arbitrary operation when the same key is in more than 1 dict (not necessarily add).

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe)

Comment: Using `collections.Counter`, you can convert dictionaries to Counter objects, add them and then recast the result as dictionary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any pythonic way to combine two dicts (adding values for keys that appear in both)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe)

Answer (score 3):

Use `collections.Counter`. It will help you.

```
from collections import Counter
A = Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
B = Counter({'b': 10, 'c': 11})
print(dict(A+B))
```

Output

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 12, 'c': 11}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the **union of all the keys** in both the dictionary, and just add values from both the dictionary using `dict.get()` with default value as 0, you can use dictionary-comprehension.

```py
def merge(d1, d2):
    keys = set(d1.keys()).union(d2.keys())
    return {k: d1.get(k,0)+d2.get(k,0) for k in keys}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
>>> merge(x, y)
{'c': 11, 'a': 1, 'b': 12}
```

**SPEED COMPARISON (>4X Faster)**:

```py
using merge (custom function): 
2.99 µs ± 574 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

using Counter: 
14.2 µs ± 709 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

After **UPDATE** to the question :

You can just modify the function a bit using `*args` if you want to do it for any number of dictionaryies:

```py
def merge(*args):
    keys = set()
    for arg in args:
        keys = keys.union(arg.keys())
    return {k: sum(arg.get(k,0) for arg in args) for k in keys}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
>>> merge(x, y, z)
{'a': 4, 'd': 5, 'c': 11, 'b': 12}
```

Comment: How would this work if I have a arbitrary number of dicts to merge?

Comment: You can use `args` and iterate over it.

Comment: @JRR, see the updated answer