# Take the Union of two dictionaries keeping all Information

Tags: python, dictionary

I found the question [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression (taking union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-taking-union-of-dictiona) where somebody wanted to merge dictionaries as union, but I want to merge dictionaries depending on the same "key" (where I don't know what key exactly) and still keep ALL information. When I tried the answer in the question I got the union but only the values of the 2nd dictionary where kept. That is not what I want. What I want is:

Lets say I have two dictionaries including lists which again includes dicts with different keys

```
myDict1 = [
  {'key1': 'list1'},
  {'key2': 'list2'},
  {'key3': 'list3'}
] 

myDict2 = [
  {'key4': 'list4'},
  {'key1': 'list5'},
  {'key3': 'list6'},
  {'key5': 'list7'}
]
```

now I want to merge the dictionaries where the keys have the same value, e.g., `key1` but I don't know what `key1` is so i can't use a criteria like `=='key1'`.

Resulting in (I use the "union_with_keys_and_values_from_both" to make sure that you understand what I want to achieve)

```
myMergedDict = [
  {'key1': 'union_with_keys_and_values_from_both(list1,list5)'},
  {'key2': 'list2'},
  {'key3': 'union_with_keys_and_values_from_both(list3,list6)'},
  {'key4': 'list7'},
  {'key5': 'list8'},
]
```

So every value of both dictionaries should be kept when merged.

Further remark:

lets say

```
list1 = (dict1)

list5 = (dict2, dict3)

dict1 = [
  {'key1': 'value1'},
  {'key2': 'value2'},
  {'key3': 'value3'}
] 

dict2 = [
  {'key4': 'value4'},
  {'key2': 'value5'},
  {'key5': 'value6'}
]

dict3 = [
  {'key6': 'value7'},
  {'key4': 'value8'},
  {'key7': 'value9'}
]
```

Then union_with_keys_and_values_from_both(list1,list5) should result in

```
unionList1List5 = [
  {'key1': 'value1'},
  {'key2': ('value2', 'value5')},
  {'key3': 'value3'}
  {'key4': ('value4', 'value8')},
  {'key5': 'value6'}    
  {'key6': 'value7'},
  {'key7': 'value9'}
]
```

Comment: what does `union_with_keys_and_values_from_both` mean(what python  type do you want)?

Comment: I want a new dict which have the keys and values of both dicts and not only from one.

Comment: it can have only one key, and the value type should be a list?

Comment: I edited my question and hope that it is clear now want I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If your union operation would be concatenate, this should do it:

```
a = {'a': 'foo', 'b':'bar', 'c': 'baz'}
b = {'a': 'spam', 'c':'ham', 'x': 'blah'}

r = dict(a.items() + b.items() +
    [(k, a[k] + b[k]) for k in set(b) & set(a)])
```

Which will give you this:

```
>>> a = {'a': 'foo', 'b':'bar', 'c': 'baz'}
>>> b = {'a': 'spam', 'c':'ham', 'x': 'blah'}
>>>
>>> r = dict(a.items() + b.items() +
...     [(k, a[k] + b[k]) for k in set(b) & set(a)])
>>> print(r)
{'a': 'foospam', 'x': 'blah', 'c': 'bazham', 'b': 'bar'}
>>>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11012181/926014

You can basically apply any operation/function for the a[k] and b[k].

Example:

For tuple:

```
>>> r = dict(a.items() + b.items() + [(k, (a[k],b[k])) for k in set(b) & set(a)])
>>> print(r)
{'a': ('foo', 'spam'), 'x': 'blah', 'c': ('baz', 'ham'), 'b': 'bar'}
```

For list:

```
>>> r = dict(a.items() + b.items() + [(k, [a[k],b[k]]) for k in set(b) & set(a)])
>>> print(r)
{'a': ['foo', 'spam'], 'x': 'blah', 'c': ['baz', 'ham'], 'b': 'bar'}
```

Comment: As long as by "union" the OP means "concatenate the strings"...

Comment: You can basically do any operation there.. between a elemend and b element with the same key

Comment: Of course, I would suggest you to make that explicit in your answer though, the OP seems a bit vague on what the union actually is and, as you said, it's fairly easy to replace the concatenation with any `union(a,b)` definition.

Comment: The question contains a list of dictionaries. But, you seem to have taken it differently.

Comment: I edited my question so it is clear that I don't mean concatenate but make a list of it.

Comment: @matlabalt I added examples for tuple and for list

Comment: @Zatarra it doesn't work for me, it says *** TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat confusingly worded, given that you're not actually attempting to take the union of two dictionaries. You've also labelled variables as `dict1`, `MyDict1` and `merged_dict`, despite the fact that they're not actually dictionaries, but lists of dictionaries. Regardless, here's a solution to your problem that makes use of `itertools.groupby` (documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby))

```
from itertools import groupby    

dict_list1 = [
  {'key1': 'dict1'},
  {'key2': 'dict2'},
  {'key3': 'dict3'}
] 

dict_list2 = [
  {'key4': 'dict4'},
  {'key1': 'dict5'},
  {'key3': 'dict6'},
  {'key5': 'dict7'}
]

def first_key_of_dict(x):
    return next(iter(x))

grouped = groupby(sorted(dict_list1 + dict_list2, key=first_key_of_dict), key=first_key_of_dict)

def get_result(k, tupled_g):
    if len(tupled_g) == 1:
        return tupled_g[0]
    return {k: tuple(x[k] for x in tupled_g)}

combined_list = [get_result(k, tuple(g)) for k, g in grouped]

print(combined_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'key1': ('dict1', 'dict5')}, {'key2': 'dict2'}, {'key3': ('dict3', 'dict6')}, {'key4': 'dict4'}, {'key5': 'dict7'}]
```

Comment: you are right, I was wrong with the dicts, it should be lists of dicts. I changed my question.