# Combine more than two dict at once (summing the values that appear in more than one dict)

Tags: python, dictionary

Inspired from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe)

I have an arbitrary number of dictionaries (coming from a generator)

```
a = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
b = {"c": 1, "d": 1}
c = {"a": 2, "b": 2}
...
```

I want to have a final dictionary that contains the following values for each key:

- If the key appears only in one dictionary, keep this value
- If the key appears in multiple dictionaries, the final value is the sum of the values in the individual dicts.

In my example, the result would be `{"a": 3, "b": 4, "c": 4, "d": 1}`

Based on the answer of the question linked above, I can use `collections.Counter` when having a set number of dictionaries, like this:

```
from collections import Counter

dict(Counter(a) + Counter(b) + Counter(c))
```

However, the number of dictionaries I have can be very large, is there any smart one-liner (or close) I can use to get this "sum" I am interested in ?

Sadly, using `sum(Counter(d) for d in (a,b,c))` raises a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Counter'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track with `sum`, with one exception. `sum` has a parameter of `start` that is the value summing starts at, which defaults to 0. This means Python tried to add Counter object to 0, thus error. Changing this value to `Counter()` lets us use `Counter`'s `__add__` method to achieve what we need.

```
from collections import Counter

a = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
b = {"c": 1, "d": 1}
c = {"a": 2, "b": 2}

dicts = [a,b,c]

counters = [Counter(single_dict) for single_dict in dicts]

total = sum(counters, start = Counter())

print(total) # Counter({'b': 4, 'c': 4, 'a': 3, 'd': 1})
```

Comment: Perfect this is exactly what I was looking for ! Seems like reading the doc for even the most basic functions helps :) Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I have come up with

```
total = Counter()

for d in (a,b,c):
     total += Counter(d)
     # Also works with total.update(d)
```

Which is fine, but cannot be used with e.g a comprehensive list so I keep the question open

Comment: This seems like the right answer. Your `for` loop already deals with iterables.

Comment: just replace `(a,b,c)` with whatever generator produces the dictionaries and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Without importing anything and achieving a plain Python dictionary as the final output, you could do this:

```
a = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
b = {"c": 1, "d": 1}
c = {"a": 2, "b": 2}

z = dict()

for d in a, b, c:
    for k, v in d.items():
        z[k] = z.get(k, 0) + v

print(z)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 4, 'd': 1}
```